# Concurrent requests not working in Siege - Http stress testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance-testing, benchmarking, stress-testing, siege

I'm testing an app located in a AWS EC2 instance via a POST request.

I'm posting an image with the url in the form of a json string by converting it to base64. All the settings are in place. The problem is that even though I'm sending 10 concurrent requests for the same image, by using the -c parameter, only the first request gets processed and the Siege stress test stops.

[image]

This is the code I'm using

```
'siege -c10 -r11 --content-type "application/json" -g 'http://www.hello.com POST {"img": "test64", fname: "img.jpg"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `-g` command since that's for GET requests and not for POST

```
'siege -c10 -r11 --content-type "application/json"  'http://www.hello.com POST {"img": "test64", fname: "img.jpg"}'
```